# Иконки к пунктам меню (SlidingMenu)

Tags: android, listview, java, adapter

Нужно, чтобы с каждым пунктом меню стояла иконка как на [картике](http://piccy.info/view3/6639733/f6fede44d83c2d7d28820c005f9592c9/). Метод setMenuItems() отправляет только текст.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    protected static MainActivity instance;
    protected static SlidingMenu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.instance = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        width = (width/100) * 80;

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.sidemenu);
        menu.setBehindWidth(width);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        this.setMenuItems();
    }
    public static MainActivity getActivity(){
        return MainActivity.instance;
    }
    public static ListView getSideMenuList(){
        return (ListView)   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sidemenu);
    }
    protected void setMenuItems(){
        String[] items = {"Пункт номер 1","Пункт номер 2","Пункт номер 3","Пункт номер 4"};
        MainActivity.getSideMenuList().setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(MainActivity.getActivity(), R.layout.sidemenu_item, R.id.text1, items));

    }
}
```

Comment: Надо написать свой адаптер для ListView вместо ArrayAdapter.